# Should I use smart pointers for passing "this"

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

Coming from mostly C#, I am going through the exercise of understanding how best to manage object ownership in c++, so bear with me.

I have a `Bus` class which has a method called `OpenChannel` that returns a `Channel` object. The `Bus` keeps a list of channels, because if the `Bus` is closed, all channels should be closed. If an individual channel is closed, the bus remains open, but the channel should be removed from the `Bus` open channel list.

The way I planned on handling this was as follows:

```
std::unique_ptr<Channel> Bus::OpenChannel(int channel_number){
  int handle = //call dll to open channel
  
  auto chnl = std::make_unique<Channel>(this, channel_number, handle);
  this->open_channels_.push_back(chnl);
}

void Bus::OnChannelClosed(Channel channel){
    //remove from open_channels_
}
```

and then in the channel class, there is a close method

```
void Channel::Close(){
  //make call to dll to close channel
  owning_bus_->OnChannelClosed(channel);
}
```

What I'm wondering is two fold -- first, for the bus being passed to the channel object's constructor, should I just use a regular pointer, or should I use a smart pointer? If a smart pointer, does it make sense to wrap "this" up in one? And two, it doesn't quite sit right with me that the bus has a public `OnChannelClosed` method that is exposed for any object to call. This could result in the Bus removing the channel due to a call from a non-channel object. I could make the `Channel` a friend of the `Bus` class, but my gut feel is there may be a better way.

**edit:**

based on some responses I figured I'd add more info. "Bus" wraps up a dll which can be initialized and uninitialized (and reinitialized again if required). When it is uninitialized, all open channel handles go invalid per the docs. I am starting to think my library wrapper should have an Initialize, Uninitialize, and "CreateChannel" method which returns a Channel which can then be operated on. Theoretically, I will never be uninitializing the bus while channels are open. But should it happen, I was hoping to gracefully manage that. However, if I'm exposing channel, there is a of course the possibility the channel object being used in another location goes invalid if the bus is uninitialized.

I think that the best way to handle this if possible is not allow the bus to be uninitialized as long as there are open channels. Maybe a shared pointer can be used to manage this? Or maybe channel shouldn't be exposed at all and Bus methods should all take a channel number as an input, and then the calls will be delegated to the correct channel.

Comment: Search the internet for "C++ factory design pattern".

Comment: You do not need `OnChannelClosed`. Make `open_channels_` to contain `std::weak_ptr`.

Comment: If `Bus` is supposed to be the owner of `Channel`, the class should imho look something like this: `class Bus { std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Channel>> m_channels; public:  Channel& OpenChannel(int channelNumber) { ... return *m_channels.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Channel>(this, channelNumber, handle));} void CloseChannel(size_t channelIndex) {...} };`

Comment: Whichever way you decide to jump, `OpenChannel` is conceptually wrong. You can't be returning an `unique_ptr` and still keep track of it in your own array. That's the very definition of a shared pointer (`shared_ptr`).

Comment: @Blindy - Maybe the right answer is return a const reference to the channel object, keep that object managed by the bus class, and wrap all channel methods in the bus class itself. Each Bus method would delegate to the appropriate channel. I would just need a channel input to nearly all bus methods, which also gave me the feeling something wasn't quite scoped correctly.

Comment: No, that's still wrong. Imagine you're saving and using that channel reference long after the channel gets removed (and so the unique pointer class deletes it). Your reference will fail with an access violation exception if you're lucky, or straight up corrupt memory if you're not.

Comment: Creating a `shared_ptr` from `this` is almost always wrong, too. You get to use that *once* - if you do it twice, the different shared_ptrs don't know about each other and calamity breaks loose. If you have two shared_ptrs for the same object you have to get the second one by copying the first one. `enable_shared_from_this` is sometimes useful.

Comment: @gfree What is supposed to happen when `Bus` is destroyed and users still hold references to open channels? Is the lifetime of `Bus` supposed to be extended until all channel references are relinquished or is this a scenario that the user is not allowed to cause? What is supposed to happen if users give up all their references to an open channel? Is the channel supposed to remain open until explicitly closed or `Bus` is destroyed or should it be closed automatically? Does `Bus` need a list of channels at all? You'll need to consider such questions to find a good ownership policy.

Comment: @
user17732522
added an edit which hopefully gives a bit more info

Comment: *“first, for the bus being passed to the channel object's constructor, should I just use a regular pointer, or should I use a smart pointer?”* — Neither. Use a reference. A smart pointer is flat out wrong; you don’t mean to transfer the ownership of `this` out of your method into the `Channel` constructor. A raw pointer is nullable — one extra thing to worry about. A `Bus&` reference fits the bill here.

Comment: *“two, it doesn't quite sit right with me that the bus has a public OnChannelClosed method that is exposed for any object to call”* — The design looks flawed. If `Channel`s are shared by multiple users of the `Bus`, cache them in the `Bus` and hand out a `std::shared_ptr`, not a `str::unique_ptr`. Then, when all users of a `Channel` stop using it, `std::shared_ptr` will dispose of the shared instance automatically and maintain  thread-safe reference counting along the way. Ultimately, make `Channel`’s destructor deregister itself from the `Bus` upon destruction.

Comment: Since the `Channels` have a link to the `Bus` you can't delete the `Bus` until all `Channel` are deleted unless you use a `weak_ptr` and locking. I would make the `Bus` a `shared_ptr` with a private constructor and a static `create` function returning a `shared_ptr<Bus>`. Each `Channel` unregisters itself in the destructor and `Bus` deletes itself when the last `shared_ptr<Bus>` goes out of scope. For informational purposes you can have a `std::vector<std::weak_ptr<Channel>> closed_channels;` (if channels have some sort of ID a map would be better).

Comment: The `Bus` should also use `std::vector<std::weak_ptr<Channel>>` so that when the last users `std::shared_ptr<Channel>` goes out of scope the Channel is destroyed. The `Bus` should not keep the `Channel` alive when the user drops it.

Answer (score 0):

With regards to your first question:

> What I'm wondering is two fold -- first, for the bus being passed to
> the channel object's constructor, should I just use a regular pointer,
> or should I use a smart pointer?

Smart pointers are incredibly useful because they remove the need for manual memory tracking. In the example you provided, your Bus class only needs a pointer to a Channel so it can keep track of which Channel instance contains it. In this context, there is no need to use a smart pointer, since all bus instances should be destroyed before the channel that holds them.

> And two, it doesn't quite sit right with me that the bus has a public
> OnChannelClosed method that is exposed for any object to call.

If all that you're concerned is that no other class other than Bus should be able to invoke the method `OnChannelClosed`, you can always make Bus a friend class of Channel, and set the method `OnChannelClosed` as private or protected.

It feels however, that you are trying to manage memory with two different approaches here, though:

1- You want Channel to keep track of all Bus instances, and

2- You want to use smart pointer so you don't need to keep track of memory at all.

One thing I noticed is that `Bus::OpenChannel` stores a unique_ptr inside a vector, and, (presumably) returns that same unique_ptr as the output of the function. This is not possible. As the name suggests, unique pointers can only be owned by one object. If you need multiple objects to have access to the pointer, you should use a shared_ptr instead.